# Output live football scores (real time) via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, wifi, text-to-speech

I have a personal project in mind but I don't know where to start.

For example: Barcelona - Real Madrid.
When one of the teams scores a goal, I want to output this via my Bluetooth speaker. for example:
Barcelona scored 1 goal. it's 1-0 now.

[image]

Comment: It is not too hard to do but would be great to know OS you use because solution may vary.

Comment: Windows 11 for my pc. and ios for my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I have a rough idea. Try using python to scrape the live score from the internet. Then when that score is scraped, you can use a Text to speech package and connect that to your speaker. You can program the speaker to say different teams scores at different times.

Recap:
Scrape online scores with python, use text to speech on the scraped scores.

Comment: To be honest, I've never worked with python. my experience lies in designing websites and such haha. something like this: https://pythonbasics.org/text-to-speech/ ?

Comment: Yes! Even if youre not experienced in python there are quick and easy web scraping tutorials on youtube. 5 mins is all you need. Search up "how to scrape web with python" and you'll get your answer. If you wont do that, Im kinda sure you can try with JS

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It sound's difficult haha. But, i'll give it a try!